# Replacing Some Elements in XML [Sample XML Provided]

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I have an xml document that looks like this.I have a XML file structured as below.
Sample XML is as follows:

```
    <Dr.Watson>
    <Bugs>
      <Bug Name="Bug.add --> AAAAAAAAAAAA">
        <criteria>
          <includeFilterSets>
            <filterSet>
              <filter>
                <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
                <operator>
                  <name>Equals</name>
                </operator>
                <value>Dr.Watson</value>
              </filter>
            </filterSet>
          </includeFilterSets>
          <grouping>
            <groupBy>
              <name>STATUS</name>
            </groupBy>
          </grouping>
          <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
          <entityToSearch>
            <name>BUG</name>
          </entityToSearch>
        </criteria>
      </Bug>
      </Bugs>

  </Dr.Watson>
```

I want to replace some of elements in the XML file like below:

```
<Dr.Watson>
<Bugs>
  <Bug Name="Bug.add --> AAAAAAAAAAAA">
    <criteria>
      <includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
          <filter>
            <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
            <operator>
              <name>Equals</name>
            </operator>
            <value>Dr.Watson</value>
          </filter>
        </filterSet>
      </includeFilterSets>
      <grouping>
        <groupBy>
          <name>STATE</name>
        </groupBy>
      </grouping>
      <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
      <entityToSearch>
        <name>BUG</name>
      </entityToSearch>
    </criteria>
  </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  </Dr.Watson>
```

i would like to change the available under  followed by  as State.
Please suggest.

Comment: -1 for: Bad title, no effort on your own and for just pasting two XML files here, without highlighting the differences.

Comment: I failed to [find 10 differences](http://img7.joyreactor.com/pics/post/funny-pictures-auto-joke-diffetence-381637.jpeg) in this game - both xml look same for me

Comment: The only difference I could find was `STATUS` vs `STATE`... So why don't you just do a find and replace?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: STATUS vs STATE

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yeah, that's it. You won :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var groupByName = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//groupBy/name");
groupByName.Value = "STATE";
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```