# How can i replace the xml elements with new elements in c#

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I would like to replace the existing elements inthe xml tag with the new ones.
Sample XML is as follows:

```
<Dr.Watson>
<Bugs>
  <Bug Name="Bug.add --> AAAAAAAAAAAA">
    <criteria>
      <includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
          <filter>
            <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
            <operator>
              <name>Equals</name>
            </operator>
            <value>Dr.Watson</value>
          </filter>
        </filterSet>
      </includeFilterSets>
      <grouping>
        <groupBy>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </groupBy>
      </grouping>
      <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
      <entityToSearch>
        <name>BUG</name>
      </entityToSearch>
    </criteria>
  </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  </Dr.Watson>
```

Code so far i have :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_InputFile);
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("/Dr.Watson/Bugs/Bug");


//create node and add value
//Console.WriteLine(mxpwr.Value);
XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "grouping", null);
XmlNode node11 = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "groupBy", null);
XmlNode node12 = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", null);

//Create Title Node
XmlNode Test_11 = doc.CreateElement("grouping");
XmlNode Test_22 = doc.CreateElement("groupBy");
XmlNode Test_44 = doc.CreateElement("name");

//add value for it
Test_11.InnerText = ("");
Test_22.InnerText = ("");
Test_44.InnerText = ("");

//create Url node
//XmlNode Test_445 = doc.CreateElement("sai");
Test_44.InnerText = ("STATE");

//add to parent node
Test_11.AppendChild(Test_22);
Test_22.AppendChild(Test_44);

//add to elements collection
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Test_11);
Test_11.AppendChild(Test_22);
Test_22.AppendChild(Test_44);
```

Please suggest and help me as i am new to c# for xml scenarios.Thanks.Also, please note that i dont want to save these edits and want to use the edited xml runtime for the execution of APIs.

Comment: What is the exact purpose of your question ? If I understand you well, you could just use the `Replace()` method on your raw XML (if it's for test only). Otherwise, I don't really know what's your problem.

Comment: You're the same guy that a few hours ago posted almost the exact same question, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696435/replacing-some-elements-in-xml-sample-xml-provided. If the *only* thing you want to do is to change "STATUS" to "STATE", then read the whole xml into a string and then `Replace("STATUS", "STATE")` and you're done!

Comment: @Corak thanks.. actually i want to create the complete tags and then replace as i need to use this workflow later.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a node via the XML-DOM API (`XmlDocument` et al):

1. Get an instance of [`XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlnode) (or a subclass), `parent`, representing the parent element of the node you want to replace.
2. Use [`parent.RemoveChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild) to remove the old node.
3. Use [`parent.AppendChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild) to add the new node.

(As an alternative to #3 use [`parent.InsertAfter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter) or [`parent.InsertBefore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertbefore.aspx) and a reference to another child to place the new node amongst other existing children.)

You code in the question appears to be constructing a new XML document from scratch: why would you want to replace a node—just create the right one first time. To modify an existing XML document use one of the static [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) methods to load and parse the existing document, use the various search and navigation methods to get the reference in #1 above, then apply the above steps, and finally save as normal.

Comment: @ Richard. Thanks. actually i would like to replace the below specified value in the xml runtime :                                <grouping>
        <groupBy>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </groupBy>
      </grouping>

Comment: @user2764162 See my A: this process applies to *any* node (and its children, if any)

Comment: Does it goes that way : XmlNode Step1 = doc.ParentNode; to locate the <grouping> node.

Comment: How can i locate the <grouping> as the parent node using parentnode.

Comment: @user2764162: one way is `xmlDoc["Bugs"]["Bug"]["criteria"]["grouping"]` using the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas.aspx) property of `XmlNode`. Personally I would probably use XPath (but that's more advanced), but would depend on whether a single file has multiple `<Bug>` elements and if I just wanted the first etc.

Comment: well i dont have multiple <Bug> nodes in my xml.i guess the earlier approach is fine.can you please draft a code for me as i really not getting through using the references.Thanks